# Monitoring NGINX with telegraf Container

Tags: nginx, containers, reverse-proxy, telegraf

I am trying to follow the post [telegraf container](https://hub.docker.com/_/telegraf/) monitor the nginx (installed on CentOS) through the telegraf container. But keep getting error as below

```
2018-09-19T01:31:00Z E! Error in plugin [inputs.nginx]: error making HTTP request to https://127.0.0.1/nginx_status: Get https://127.0.0.1/nginx_status: x509: certificate is valid for 52.37.147.151, not 127.0.0.1
```

In the NGINX, the configuration is like

```
http {
  ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /**/**/**/**.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /**/**/**/**.key;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers '*****';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ...
    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:443;

        location /nginx_status {
            auth_request off;
            stub_status on;
            access_log off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
        }
     }
}
```

When I run "curl -k https://127.0.0.1/nginx_status", it works fine that I got basic status of nginx connection. 
But when I stated to run the telegraf container, it keeps the error above..

Any clue what happened? Thanks.

Comment: the certificate you are using is issued to `52.37.147.151` not `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't notice in [telegraf nginx plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/nginx) there is an option to ignore the authentication. With this set to true it works for me. 
"insecure_skip_verify = true"

Comment: thats a terrible idea to skip verification and not recommend at all!!

Answer (score 0):

The certificate path you provided in nginx config is issued to the localhost only. You can verify it by looking at the certificate in text mode,

```
cat <certificate-file-path> | openssl x509 -text
```

and look for `Subject Alternative Name` and `Subject`.

The solution is to generate a new certificate that is issued for your desired host/ip.

Comment: Thanks Sufiyan for answering the question. Because I need to connect to localhost, it turns out I can just skip certificate verify in the plugin.